# Custom table layout for variable description

Tags: tables, lists, line-breaking, multicolumn, layout

#### What do I want to do

I want to create a table for presenting a lot of variables in a clear way. Each class does get its own table containing up to one hundred variables, so the the table has to be able to span multiple pages.

[image: The code will produce this example]

#### What is my problem

- I don't have a clean way to make a list in a multicolumn (last caption in picture) and to shift this list under the corresponding caption. The variable groups under the caption don't fit to the head of the table anymore but belong into this class so I don't  want make a new table for them. Maybe i will add a custom head for this section?
- Also: Sometimes there are large strings or long values which don't fit into the last column. The solution I implemented in *\longvalue* is quite messy. And the way I indent the variables and captions on the different levels seems overly complicated.

As I am fairly new to LaTeX I will be grateful for every tip or suggestion you have regarding the layout.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% -------------------------- Table Layering Commands ------------------------- %
\newcommand{\varlone}[3]{\MakeUppercase{\ttfamily #1} & #2 & \ttfamily{#3} \\}
\newcommand{\caplone}[1]{\addlinespace[0.5em]\multicolumn{3}{l}{#1} \\ \cmidrule(l{.5em}){1-3}}
\newcommand{\varltwo}[3]{\enspace\MakeUppercase{\ttfamily #1} & #2 & \ttfamily{#3} \\}
\newcommand{\capltwo}[1]{\addlinespace[0.5em]\multicolumn{3}{>{\enspace}l}{#1} \\ \cmidrule(l{1em}){1-3}}
\newcommand{\varlthree}[3]{\quad\MakeUppercase{\ttfamily #1} & #2 & \ttfamily{#3} \\}

% --------------------------- Variable Description --------------------------- %
\newlist{optList}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[optList]{nosep,label={},left=0.5em}
\newenvironment{varopts}{\begin{optList}\footnotesize}{\end{optList}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\leavevmode}
\newcommand{\longvalue}[2][5cm]{\makebox[0em][r]{\parbox[t]{#1}{\raggedleft #2}}}
\newcommand{\arraysize}[1]{(Array (#1))}

% ------------------------------ Ugly hardcoded ------------------------------ %
\newcommand{\sensors}[2]{\multicolumn{3}{l}{\quad #1 \enspace {\ttfamily{#2}}} \\}

% ----------------------------- Table Environment ---------------------------- %
\newenvironment{classtable}[2]{\begin{longtable}{l p{0.63\linewidth} r}
    \caption{class = \MakeUppercase{#1}}\label{tab:class_#1}\\
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{#2}\\
    \midrule
    Name & Description & Value \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \midrule
    Name & Description & Value \\
    \midrule
    \endhead}{\bottomrule\end{longtable}}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

\begin{document}

\begin{classtable}{classname}{A short description of the contents of the class spanning multiple rows. This table has to feature a lot of variables and might span multiple pages.}
    %
    \caplone{A caption on layer one}
    \varltwo{var1}{This is the first variable}{\longvalue{long string value\\with linebreak}}
    \varltwo{testvar}{Variable on layer two with arraysize \arraysize{2}}{1.5,4.0}
    %
    \capltwo{A caption on layer two}
    \varlthree{var3}{Variable on layer three with description \begin{varopts}
        \item 1 = Description of first option
        \item 2 = Description of second option
    \end{varopts}}{2}
    \varlthree{var4}{Variable on layer three}{test}
    %
    \varlone{var5}{Standalone variable on layer one}{3}
    \capltwo{List variable options in a caption
        \quad\makebox[0em][t]{\parbox[t]{15cm}{\footnotesize
        {\ttfamily{-X}} (0 = off, 1 = on) Enables something \\
        {\ttfamily{-XX}} (1 = none, 2 = few) Calculates something}}}
    \sensors{One type with a long name}{sen1X = 1, sen1XX = 1}
    \sensors{Another type}{sen2X = 0, sen2XX = 2}
\end{classtable}

\end{document}
```